# Nuxt EventBus - usage for many events

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, event-bus

in my Nuxt app I have a Canvas that listens for mouse events. Now I want to send those mouse events to the DOM, everything is working fine. But I'm concerned that there are too many events for Vue, because there is like thousands of them. When I switch to the Vue dev tools, my Computer already begins to stutter. I feel like Vue is only made for simple click events, but I'm using it for a ton. Is there a better way to handle that?

```
init(){
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", this.mouseMove.bind(this));
}
mouseMove(e){
    EventBus.$emit("MOUSEMOVE", e);
}
```

Comment: google out  ⏩ "debounce mousemove event in javascript"

Answer (score 0):

It's okay if you need to add certain event listeners here and there. Just make sure you remove them when to component is destroyed, e.g.

```
mounted() {
  window.addEventListener('eventName', yourMethod);
},

beforeDestroy() {
  window.removeEventListener('eventName', yourMethod);
}
```

Comment: `debounce` would be helpful for your solution. Otherwise browser may stuck on limited resource browser.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `debouncer` for a short time limit.

I'm guessing that your DOM is not updating on every event and it takes some to self update. So slow down the event bus emit like in every 50/100 ms there will be an event fire. You can emit to event bus on every 50 MiliSecond or as per as your need. That would be helpful even if you solve the problem in other way.